# Alert policy does not create incident

Tags: newrelic

I have an NRQL policy with custom parameter (i’m sending from application every 5 mins).
Query looks like

```
SELECT latest(my_param) FROM Transaction
```

with window duration 10 minutes and streaming method EventTimer=5s

I’ve configured it in a way to receive incident immediately, but even when I see on graphs voilations - no incident was created. Does anyone have any ideas what’s wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data types. NewRelic has data types. Who could imagine that 0 + 123 + 125 is 0123125 and not 248?
Changing query to `SELECT latest(numeric(MY_PARAM)) FROM Transaction`  solved all problems.